# Awk: Remove text after last space in row

Tags: linux, bash, text, awk, text-processing

I have a tab-delimited text file in the following format.

```
Col1  | Col2  | Col3
123.0 | 534.2 | Blah0 2031/23/12
23.00 | 786.2 | Blah1 2033/01/01
12.40 | 343.0 | Blah2 2031/27/11
```

I need to remove all the characters after the space from the last column. So my output would be

```
Col1  | Col2  | Col3
123.0 | 534.2 | Blah0
23.00 | 786.2 | Blah1
12.40 | 343.0 | Blah2
```

How should I go about this using `Awk` or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR != 1 { sub(/ [^ ]*$/, "", $NF) } 1' filename
```

That is:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }           # the output should be separated the same way as
                             # the input

NR != 1 {                    # in all lines except the header line:
  sub(/ [^ ]*$/, "", $NF)    # replace the last space and everything after it
}                            # in the last field ($NF)  with the empty string
                             # (i.e., remove it)

1                            # in all lines: print.
```

If there can be several spaces in the last field and you want to remove everything after the first space, use `sub(/ .*/, "", $NF)` instead. It wasn't entirely clear in the question what should happen in such a case.

Comment: Note that this `awk` code will trim `Col3` from the header.

Comment: @Helio The ` | ` and spaces surrounding them are supposed to be tabs, as I understand it. But I suppose I could put something in the answer for field names with tabs; you're right that it seems unlikely that the transformation should be done on the header line.

Comment: What about a more unix-like solution: `(rev | cut -d ' ' -f 2-7 | rev) < file`?

Comment: That makes a number of assumptions about the data with which I'm not entirely comfortable. One could be handled by using `-f 2-` instead of `-f 2-7`, but what if there's a line in which the last field doesn't contain a space at all? It's tabular data; awk was pretty much made for this. (Also, I disagree that awk is not unix-like, considering that it is part of POSIX :P)

Comment: Ok, you have reason :-((